# Using a jQuery to pull a random banner image in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to use jQuery in order to get my webpage to display random banner images from a select pool in my `images/banners/` directory. From what I currently have, the script does not pull any image from the possible options, and also drags my footer to the top of the page for some reason. The script is supposed to append the randomly selected image to the `#banner div` and uses CSS to achieve this as well.

I've tried changing the file paths and messing with the appendTo function and the actual CSS itself to no avail. Since I'm using this script in a WordPress theme, the PHP code with the `get_template_directory_uri()` function is needed to correctly form a path to the images after the theme is uploaded.

Here's the script as it is right now:

```
    <script>
        var images = ['shelbysquare1.png', 'test1.png', 'test2.png', 'lake.jpg', 'fields.png'];
        $('<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/banners/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner');
    </script>
```

And here is the banner id in its current state:

```
#banner {
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-position: top left;
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   z-index: -2; }
```

I intentionally have the z-index as lower so that the navbar goes above the banner, and the position is set to absolute to ensure it stays on the top left of the page at all times. Also, the `<div id="banner">` tag for the image is within the `<body>` tag, and is the first div there, above the navbar even. I don't get any errors from what I can tell either.

I'm not an expert with these things just yet, so any advice or suggested changes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What value do you get inside img src attribute? Also, why are you using JS for this at all? Why don't you simply print out image path with PHP?

Comment: When I preview my theme, the value I get is this: `$('<img src="http://wordpress.co.shelby.in.us/wp-content/themes/theme_files/images/banners/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '">').appendTo('#banner');` @MilanG

Comment: So it looks like it's not appending a full image path to the string for some reason. Also, I'm using Javascript because it'll load images on the client side and because I can set a <noscript> default banner. @MilanG

Comment: are you using child theme? get_template_directory_uri() is for parrent theme and get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for child theme.

Comment: No, the theme I'm using should be a parent theme because it's completely custom. However, I could be wrong so correct me if I'm misunderstanding that terminology. @TobiasM

Comment: Did you try using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() as TobiasM suggested? That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but there are a few things that might be wrong. To easier debug it you could re-factor the code like this. And pay attention to whatever the console logs out.

```
<script>
var images = [ 'shelbysquare1.png', 'test1.png', 'test2.png', 'lake.jpg', 'fields.png' ],
    randomImage = images[ Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length ) ],
    themePath = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>',
    fullPath = themePath + '/images/banners/' + randomImage;

var $img = $('<img/>', {
    src: fullPath
});

$img.appendTo('#banner');

console.log($img);
</script>
```

By error.logging (or using breakpoints in your browsers developer tools), you can check the value of any variable you have declared.

In the script above I'm logging out the DOM-object we've just created. If you're using Chrome expected output in your console should look like this:

```
a.fn.init [img, selector: "<img/>", context: {…}]
0: img
context: {src: "http://hostname.domain/wp- 
content/themes/themename/images/banners/test2.png"}
length: 1
selector: "<img/>"
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Make sure the src-value is correctly pointing to your theme folder. As mentioned by TobiasM in the comments get_template_directory_uri() returns the parent theme.

If the value is correct, but you don't see any image. Make sure that when the script runs, the div with id #banner is available. 
For example if you run your script in the head-tag, it will run before the div is in the DOM, so when it runs .appendTo() the target is not found.

Solve this by either running your Javascript after the DOM has been added (Right before closing the BODY-tag), or add the following callback which will run after all DOM-content has been loaded.

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: My output in the console is not exactly like that (I am using Chrome). For one, it shows as 'k.fn.init(1)'. Also, there are no brackets with img, selector and context. The 'context' attribute doesn't show up period, nor does 'selector'. Essentially, my output looks like: `k.fn.init(1) -- 0: img -- length: 1 -- __proto__: Object (0)`

Comment: Putting the script before closing the `<body>` tag fixed it! I had the script in my `<head>` tag. Thank you so much! @ninja